# How to customize Retrofit converter factory for nested level data class in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

For example, my model class name is StudentResponse

```
    class BaseConverterFactory private constructor() : Converter.Factory() {
    override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        LogUtils.d("Hello type: " + type)
        if (type === String::class.java) {
            return Converter { value -> value.string() }
        } else if (type === Int::class.java) {
            return Converter { value -> Integer.valueOf(value.string()) }
        } else if (type === Double::class.java) {
            return Converter { value -> java.lang.Double.valueOf(value.string()) }
        } else if (type === Boolean::class.java) {
            return Converter { value -> java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(value.string()) }
        }
        return null
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(): BaseConverterFactory {
            return BaseConverterFactory()
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
data class StudentResponse(
    var aggregatedValues: List<Books>?,
}

data class Books(
    var bookValue: Double?, //here retrofit should consider as int. If 34.11 is coming it should round off to 34
```

So here type is coming as StudentResponse. So the pojo structure is like this
inside StudentResponse - List - Books.kt - var bookValue: Double

But what I want is: Double to Int
inside StudentResponse - List - Books.kt - var bookValue: Double

that I'm not able to do this using my custom converter factory

Also, which is a better approach? not just for this example, Foe entire project this type of many changes will come so what to use?
::retrofit converter factory vs gson deserialization

I appreciate all answers!

Comment: Your goal is not clear. Please add your StudentResponse & Books classes. 
Show you current state and what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need your Double response to be an Int, you can use a @JsonAdapter to achieve that.

Change your Books class to:

```
data class Books(
    @JsonAdapter(DoubleToInt::class)
    var bookValue: Int?,
```

And add this class to handle the conversion:

```
class DoubleToInt : JsonDeserializer<Int?> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): Int? {

        return json?.asDouble?.roundToInt()
    }
}
```